# Adjust height of panel @media

Tags: html, css

I am trying to adjust the height of a panel body when it gets the `col-md`. I know to use media tags, but can not seem to get it to work correctly, I will post my HTML and CSS below.

```css
.panel-height {
  height: inherit;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .panel-height {
    height: 280px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-6">
  <div class="menu-item gray">
    <div class="panel-heading text-center">
      <a>
        <p>Test</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="panel-body panel-height" style="height: 250px;">
      This is the body
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems height that you set with attribute style overrids the height in css. Remove style attr and set height in CSS for both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're CSS inline styles are messing up the `@media query`. Just put them in your external CSS file. Example using `color`:

```css
.panel-height {
  color: blue;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .panel-height {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-6">
  <div class="menu-item gray">
    <div class="panel-heading text-center">
      <a>
        <p>Test</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="panel-body panel-height">This is the body</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Resize the fiddle to see it work.](http://jsfiddle.net/4ancbrvt/)

**OR** use `!important` on your `external styles` which will *override* the `inline` ones - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ancbrvt/1/)

Comment: Thank you very much, it was the inline styling that was overriding it.... Will mark as answered as soon as it allows